# Can I get Minecraft Pocket Edition for free if I've already bought the game?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft Pocket Edition has just been released and since I've already bought the game for PC I was hoping I could get the pocket edition for free. Does it do any account verification to check if you've already paid, perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389361/can-you-get-minecraft-java-for-free-if-you-have-purchased-minecraft-bedrock) (per galacticninja's answer to that question that applies both ways)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No you cannot. The game is only available from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe), for Android, or [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/minecraft-pocket-edition/id479516143) for iOS, and you must purchase it from there.

It is a separate product, so it is exempt from the Alpha/Beta *All/until release future editions free* promise.

Comment: I would assume this is right, but: Reference?

Comment: @Matthew I can attest to this from experience, having an Alpha Minecraft account and still having to buy Pocket Edition from the Android Market.

Comment: @Keaanu I'm more looking for an official statement of some sort, that would rule out any kind of arrangement to get the app that you might be unaware of.

Comment: The way the Android Market is set up doesn't really allow for that, anyway.

Comment: Not a massive revelation, but since this was answer was posted, Minecraft Pocket Edition is available for iOS as well. Just thought it would make the answer more complete.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely separate products, so having one does not mean you can get the other for free, unless of course you were talking about Minecraft PE Free Version. :)

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft PE is £5.00 (pounds) £7.00 (dollars)

They are separate games so you cannot get Minecraft PE for free.