# If I have Minecraft on Windows 10, can i get it for free on Mobile (Android)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have the Windows 10 version of Minecraft, and I was wondering if the mobile version would then be free for me since I've purchased it on PC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Bedrock and PE accounts are not linked. The only case where you would get a free account is when you've already owned the Java Edition before the Bedrock edition was released, you would get the Bedrock Edition for Windows 10 (if you were on widows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32212/can-i-get-minecraft-pocket-edition-for-free-if-ive-already-bought-the-game?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

No, the Android version of Minecraft cannot currently be obtained for free with a Windows 10 version of the game.

There used to be a [promotion](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2064007-minecraft-for-windows-10) for owners of Minecraft: Java Edition though:

> Players who have purchased Minecraft: Java Edition before October 19th, 2018 can get Minecraft for Windows 10 for free by visiting their Mojang account.